# Unable to read from file through Kafka producer

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am trying to read a file using kafka producer.Zookeeper and Broker server are running. I am able to read inputs from command prompt using Kafka producer and Consumers using below commands -

```
Kafka Producer 
kafka-console-producer --topic incoming --broker localhost:9092 

Kafka Consumer 
kafka-console-consumer --topic incoming --zookeeper localhost:2181
```

For reading from file i had tried below command line arguments -

```
kafka-console-producer -–broker-list localhost:9092 -–topic incoming --new-producer < C:\abc.txt
```

but it produced below error -

```
û is not a recognized option
```

I googled the message and it says about correcting the producer command which looks correct to me.

Comment: What is your kafka version?

Comment: its kafka_2.11-0.10.0.0

Comment: The command that i have used to read from file, is it correct?  I used (http://grokbase.com/t/kafka/users/157b71babg/kafka-producer-input-file) to confiigure it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For kafka-10 you don't need to pass --new-producer flag. Following command is working for me:

```
kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic incoming < C:\abc.txt
```

Comment: I still have to hit the above command to get value for my consumer. Doesn't it call it on it self?

Comment: I had expected it to fetch data whenever the given file is updated. How can we achieve such behaviour?

Comment: In that case, I think kafka-connect might serve your purpose. I'm not 100% sure though. Refer this link: https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart#quickstart_kafkaconnect